# Different Results Between presentViewController and pushViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, segue, uistoryboardsegue

I am a little confused as to different results I am seeing between two attempts to programatically instantiate and open a new View. I have a method that is called by an NSTimer callback (though I don't think that is so relevant), and it attempts to allocate and initialize the second view controller, and push it onto the stack (I may have my nomenclature a bit off there, sorry).

Looking at the ViewController Programming Guide and a few answers around here, I've identified two potential solutions, both of which build and run fine, but I get different results, neither of which fully work.

The first one uses the `presentViewController` method. It looks like this:

```
SecondViewController *secondView = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];
[self presentViewController:secondView animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

... and it works, in a manner of speaking. I put an NSLog in the viewDidLoad method of the SecondViewController class, and it prints. If I also set a UIColor programatically there, the screen colours. However, anything that I place on the View of this VC in my Storyboard doesn't show up - if I don't colour the View programatically, the screen is black.

The second way I tried because I thought that the code wasn't connecting to my Storyboard properly (it's an older method that still works with XIB's afaik). It looks like this:

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard_iPhone" bundle:nil];
SecondViewController *secondView = (SecondViewController *)
[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"secondView"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:secondView animated:YES];
```

... but neither the viewDidLoad nor the interface seem to respond/get called.

I also looked at a `prepareForSegue` method, but I'm not sure if it's going to make a difference, as I'm pretty sure there's something I'm missing...

I should note that I have set the Storyboard ID of the ViewController under the Identity Inspector.

If anyone can explain both the immediate solution to my problem and/or a larger explanation of the issue I'm experiencing, that would be greatly appreciated.

~ Jesse

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, thanks to Wain's answer and comments, I got this to properly programatically instantiate a new `UIViewController` that sits in my Storyboard. After making a Modal (see comment) segue to the second `UIViewController`, with a custom `Identifier`, I simply had to call the `performSegueWithIdentifier` method in my callback method from my `NSTimer`. It seems that I had way too much code, and was over thinking the need to make my second `UIViewController` programatically from within my first. Here's the relevant parts of my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    if(self.timer == nil) {
        self.timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:2.5 target:self selector:@selector(switchView) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
    }

}

- (void) switchView {
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"timerDone" sender:self];

    [timer invalidate];
    self.timer = nil;       
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first solution /issues using `presentViewController`, the creation and presentation is fine but the storyboard isn't involved at all. If you create the view content in code (like the colour) or if the `init` method loaded a NIB or something the everything would be great.

The second method looks like it should work, so it could be that the name of the storyboard is wrong, the name of the identifier is wrong, or the `navigationController` is nil.

The `prepareForSegue` method would only be called if a segue was triggered by a user interaction where the segue was configured in the storyboard or a segue specifically triggered from code.

Generally, you want to predominantly use 1 form of creating your view transitions. If you're using storyboards then that would usually be segues configured in the storyboard and linked to UI items. Then you would implement `prepareForSegue` in the 'source' view controllers to pass any additional information required be the 'destination' view controller. You should work through [this guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/UsingViewControllersinYourApplication/UsingViewControllersinYourApplication.html).

Comment: Thanks for the comments Wain. I understand what you are saying about 1 form, but in this case, I am trying to load/call a new ViewController from an NSTimer callback, so there's no way to do that through the UI, though I would like to keep using the Storyboard for the rest of my application... I guess I really need advice on how to link them, if and when that is needed...

Comment: Your comment about the navigationController being nil just triggered it for me - I had not embedded the first ViewController in a Navigation Controller - doing that makes my 2nd VC show up properly! ... however, I don't actually want these to screens to be linked in a NavController - I'm trying to make this more of a timed out splash page navigating to the main menu page, and dont want to be able to go back to the splash page...

Comment: Define a named segue from the view controller which owns the timer and trigger it from code (`performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:`).

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what this means. Do I define the segue programatically or from the Storyboard? How do I make it own the NSTimer? Etc.

Comment: The segue is defined in the storyboard (see "triggering a segue programmatically" in the guide). 'Own' just means the view controller which handles the timer action method when it fires.

Comment: Ok... I think I get it. But let me clarify one or two more things: So, I have a segue with an identifier - check. I've added the performSegueWithIdentifier method, and it's being called - check. But I am unsure as to which method of creating my subclassed UIViewController to be using, and I'm a little unsure as to the order of where it is being placed vis-a-vis the method calls...

Comment: I got this to work, thanks again (will answer momentarily). But it's interesting to note that it will only work with a Modal segue if I'm not willing to embed the ViewController in a NavigationController...